# Unable to override post method of Django UpdateView

Tags: python, django, model

I have a update view in django project. I need to override the post method because I am using multiple modelform.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Update a created a employee
    """

    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_update_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    education_form_class = EducationForm
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('employee:employee-list')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee_id = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee_id)
        education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee_id)


        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': self.form_class(instance=employee_id),
                                                    'work_form': self.work_form_class(instance=work_info),
                                                    'education_form': self.education_form_class(instance=education_info)
                                                    }
                                                )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form')
        education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form')

        # Check form validation
        if form.is_valid() and work_form.is_valid() and education_form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            work = work_form.save(commit=False)
            education = education_form.save(commit=False)
            work.employee = instance
            education.employee = instance
            work.update()
            education.update()

            return redirect('employee:employee-list')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_form': work_form,
                                                    'education_form': education_form
                                                    }
                                                )
```

When I press update button of my form, error is giving showwing "This field already exist". It means when i update the form is post data as a new form not as a update form.

Where is error in my post method?

Comment: It will only see it as an update, if you pass `instance=...` to the form, so for example `self.form_class(request.POST, instance=...)`. The fact that you made an override of `post`, means the original boilerplate logic if the `UpdateView` is not ujsed anymore. If you override both `get` and `post`, then it makes no sense anymore to use something like a `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, `DeleteView`, etc. since the idea is that it implements the boilerplate logic itself.

Comment: then how can I update multiple modelforms values?